# populating combobox depending on other one

Tags: php, html

I am trying to populate a combobox depending on another one.
 
The first one will show me all the categories and the second one all the subcategories that belongs to it.
 I have seen that there is two ways of doing it with ajax and jquery, can you please help me?

```
$sqlCmd ="SELECT DISTINCT categories.categoryID, categories.categoryName
      FROM categories
      JOIN subcategories
      ON subcategories.categoryID=categories.categoryID
      JOIN languages
      ON categories.languageID = languages.languageID
      WHERE languages.languageID =:lang;
        ";
$prepQuery = $conn ->prepare($sqlCmd);
$prepQuery->bindParam(":lang",$langid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepQuery->execute();
$resultLang= $prepQuery->fetchAll();

SELECT subcategories.subCatID,subcategories.subCatName, categories.categoryID
FROM subcategories
JOIN categories
ON subcategories.categoryID=categories.categoryID
JOIN languages
ON categories.languageID = languages.languageID
WHERE languages.languageID =1
AND categories.categoryID=1;
```

```
    <select name="comboCategories" onchange ='<?php echo  "window.location.href='#postanAd.php?comboCategories='"?>'>
        <?php
        //$counter=0;
        foreach ($resultLang as $oneRec)
        {
    echo"<option value=".$oneRec["categoryID"].">".$oneRec["categoryName"]."</option>";             
        }
       ?>
    </select>                      

    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="input-icon">             
           <a> Select a subcategory </a>
               <!-- COMBOBOX ALL SUBCATEGORIES  !-->
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you don't have many categories, you can generate all subcategories and hide them (`display:none;`), then using JavaScript (eventListener) show subcategories of selected category. If that's not the case or you want to get subcategories from server for some other reason, read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX I don't see any JavaScript in your code... Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried it but it was not working so I removed it. I will try using the eventlistener like suggested

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX and php to do this.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="comboCategories"]').on("change", function() {
        var selectVal = $('this').val();

        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'postanAd.php',                         
          data: "comboCategories="+selectVal,                                                     
          type:'post',
          //dataType: 'json',                
          success: function(data) { 
              for (var i in data) {
                 $('select[name="subcategories"]').append('<option value="">'+data[i]+'</option>');
               }
          }
        });
    });
   });
</script>
```